# Expanding a multiple instance timer to be timezone aware

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a js timer that is used to show a countdown to the end times on items that are sold in an auction format. The js I use is below.

```
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
$this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
$this.html(event.strftime('%-Dday%!D %-Hhr%!H %Mmin%!M %Ssec'));
});
});
```

I want to make this timezone aware so I searched online and found MomentJS.
I've included the moment-with-locales.min.js and moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js files and they are being correctly loaded.

I'm really struggling to get my head around how to integrate the js into my current script as the sample on the github is for a single instance timer only.
The code example they give is

```
var nextYear = moment.tz("2015-01-01 00:00", "America/Sao_Paulo");
$('#clock').countdown(nextYear.toDate(), function(event) {
$(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
});
```

Now I assume I need to apply the

```
= moment.tz("2015-01-01 00:00", "America/Sao_Paulo");
```

type code to my date which are stored in data-countdown, but I just end up with a blank space where the countdown should be.

This is what I tried to do

```
var $this = $(this), finalDate = moment.tz($(this).data('countdown'), "America/Sao_Paulo");
```

Where have I gone wrong adding the moment.tz command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using

```
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
var $this = $(this), finalDate = moment.tz($(this).data('countdown'), "Europe/London");
$this.countdown(finalDate.toDate(), function(event) {
$this.html(event.strftime('%-Dday%!D %-Hhr%!H %Mmin%!M %Ssec'));
});
});
```

Only issue I have is that the time is 1hr out. An end time of 15:00 in London should have one hour more on the countdown in Paris, but it has two hours more at the moment.